# HTML base App on AppStore

Tags: ios

Anybody can solve my confusion i have opened a url in webview (which is responsive for mobile ) then all 
      functionality is performing fine 
      like website,how can i make approve this by apple

```
 NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.ideamasale.com/";

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 [detailWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

would Apple App Review Approve this App for AppStore

Comment: Are you trying to get approval fr an app that shows everything in webview ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From section 4.2 of [Apple's App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store.

So no, they won't accept that. You must use the web as your distribution platform (via "add to home screen" and friends).

Comment: Aehmlo can you describe more  i.e (via "add to home screen" and friends).

Comment: @VikasKumar I recommend you go read [Apple's documentation on web applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) and accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

No it'll would probably not be accepted, if the only thing your app does is opening a website.
But you might want to read the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).
And specificly Section 4.2:

> **Minimum Functionality**
>   Your app should include features, content, and
>   UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not
>   particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the
>   App Store. If your App doesn't provide some sort of lasting
>   entertainment value, or is just plain creepy, it may not be accepted.
>   Apps that are simply a song or movie should be submitted to the iTunes
>   store. Apps that are simply a book or game guide should be submitted
>   to the iBooks Store.

Comment: but this app is live on app store already with webview https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/idea-masale/id1033771967?mt=8

Comment: I have no idea wether this is actually a webview just showing the website nor why did apple approve this. App approval is partially a manual process. It happens that apps "slip through" whilst they should have been declined.